# Javascript accessing other classes using functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, class

I'm new to this stuff but i'm trying to create a new instance of a class in javascript that class I also want to initialise using input, like a function.

So far I have:

```
/Class1.js
/folder/Class2.js
```

Class2.js:

```
function Class2(n) {
this.number = n;
}
```

Class1.js:

```
var instance = new Class2(1);
```

That didn't work so I tried requiring the class:

```
require('./folder/Class2.js');
```

or

```
var newClass = new require('./folder/Class2.js');
var instance = new newClass(1);
```

Neither worked and I get the error:

> Class2 is not defined

No online examples such as [this](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) haven't gone into any detail why it doesn't work just the same non-working stuff.

Comment: `class` is a reserved identifier, so you can't have a variable named `class`. In fact, in [ECMAScript 6](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-class-definitions) it is used to create classes.

Comment: They're example names so I don't have to go through all the different folders and class names that they actually are called and located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `module.exports = Class2;` to the end of you class 2 file. The value you assign will be returned when you require that file. If you don't export anything you won't be getting anything at all when you require.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be caused by the order of your JS class definitions in your HTML. You might be trying to reference Class2 in Class1 before Class2 'exists'.